# этимология слова "ружьё"?

Tags: этимология, существительные

Кто-нибудь знает происхождение слова "ружьё"? Не смог найти ни одного однокоренного слова, кроме его производных.

Comment: А слово "оружие" вам родственным не кажется?

Comment: мне казалось что это одна из форм...

Comment: [Викисловарь](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F)

Comment: плохо искали, и за это даунвоут.

Comment: ну что ж сделаешь, вспылил :) спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to Vasmer, see both `орудие` and `оружие`: http://vasmer.narod.ru/p470.htm